# Error while upgrading symfony 4.3 to 4.4 (Call to a member function generate() on null)

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to update my symfony project from 4.3 to 4.4.

In my composer.json file, I changed all "symfony/*" dependencies to point from 4.3.* to 4.4.*. I updated all dependencies by executing form terminal:

`composer.phar update --with-all-dependencies`

After the update, everything looks fine. There are a couple of warnings but I don't think that's the problem. Here is the result in the terminal:

```
      Loading composer repositories with package information
      Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
      Updating dependencies
      Nothing to modify in lock file
      Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
      Nothing to install, update or remove

      Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
      Package paypal/paypalhttp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.

      Generating autoload files
      composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
      composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
      103 packages you are using are looking for funding.
      Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

      Synchronizing package.json with PHP packages
      Don't forget to run npm install --force or yarn install --force to refresh your JavaScript dependencies!
      Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

      Executing script cache:clear [OK]
      Executing script assets:install public [OK]
```

The problem comes when I load any page in the browser, it shows this error for all the pages

```
    Call to a member function generate() on null

    in vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Extension/RoutingExtension.php (line 71)
```

[The error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiADs.png)

I found that the error gets executed when the application access any controller and tries to show the view by calling the twig file with this line:

`return $this->render('mytemplate',[]);`

I thought the problem was created by a twig conflict and tried to return a random html directly from the controller to avoid calling the twig file, however the error persists:

```
public function testController(): Response
{
    //the error happens when it executes the return
    return new Response(
        '<html><body>TEST</body></html>'
    );
}
```

My composer.json file looks like this:

```
    {
        "type": "project",
        "license": "proprietary",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.1.3",
            "ext-ctype": "*",
            "ext-iconv": "*",
            "beelab/paypal-bundle": "v1.5.0",
            "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "1.0.1",
            "curl/curl": "2.2.0",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.3",
            "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "3.0.2",
            "doctrine/orm": "^2.5.11",
            "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "2.6.0",
            "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
            "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.11",
            "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "v5.5.1",
            "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.93",
            "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.31",
            "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "v1.3.0",
            "stripe/stripe-php": "v7.14.2",
            "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
            "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/flex": "v1.12",
            "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/monolog-bundle": "v3.5.0",
            "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/serializer-pack": "v1.0.2",
            "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "v3.4.0",
            "symfony/templating": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/twig-bridge": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "v1.7.2",
            "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "4.4.*",
            "symfony/profiler-pack": "v1.0.5",
            "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.4.*"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
            "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.11",
            "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
            "symfony/test-pack": "*",
            "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
        },
        "config": {
            "preferred-install": {
                "*": "dist"
            },
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "src/",
                "Sim\\": "lib/" 
            }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "replace": {
            "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
            "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
            "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
            "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
            "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
            "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "auto-scripts": {
                "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
                "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
            },
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "@auto-scripts"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "@auto-scripts"
            ]
        },
        "conflict": {
            "symfony/symfony": "*"
        },
        "extra": {
            "symfony": {
                "allow-contrib": false,
                "require": "4.4.*"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please avoid images in your question. It doesn't help contributors. It seems you have an error in Twig. Route generators isn't created in constructor. Did you purge the cache? Did your verify the recipes are uptodate?

Comment: Have you deleted `vendor` directory before running composer ?

Comment: Hello @AlexandreTranchant. I improved to content of my question avoiding the images, thanks for your suggestion. I also thought it was a twig problem, however I tried to return directly some html from the controller to avoid calling the twig file and the same happened. I edited my question showing that at the end. I also did remove all the content of var/cache/* and var/log/* and the error continues

Comment: Hello @Hamham, thanks for your answer. Yes I removed the vendor folder and the composer.lock before executing composer.phar update --with-all-dependencies. The problem persists.

Comment: Did you check the [recipes](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5-upgrade/recipe-commands#new-recipe-commands)? Don't forget to use git and to save your project before. Some of your code will be updated.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I updated all recipes according to new versions and the problem remains.